# "Fair" game in Williams

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In [David Williams' Probability with Martingales](http://www.scribd.com/doc/79882580/Prob-Probability-With-Martingales-Williams), $\exists$ this exercise.

What's fair about a fair game?

Let $X_i$, i = 1, 2, ... be indp RVs s.t. $X_i = i^2 - 1$ with prob $1/i^2$ and $-1$ with prob $1-1/i^2$.

I find it clear that $E(X_n)=0$. However, I do not understand why:

if $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, then $S_n/n \to -1$ a.s.

My attempt:

Proving $S_n/n \to -1$ a.s. is equivalent to proving $P(S_n/n = -1 \ i.o.) = 1$ or $P(S_n/n = -1 \ ev.) = 1$. I think?

If so, I just take the first one $P(S_n/n = -1)$, sum it over n's,hope it's infinity and use Borel-Cantelli 2...after proving the events $S_n/n = -1$ are independent, of course.

$P(S_n/n = -1)$

$=P(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i = -n)$

$=P(\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} X_i=-1)$ I think?

$=\Pi_{i=1}^{n} P(X_i=-1)$ by independence

$=0$ if I plug in i=1.

Help please?

Comment: are you sure that you wrote it down right because isn't it true by strong law of large numbers that $P(\bar{X}=E(X))$ a.s. thus it should be $P(\frac{S_{n}}{n}=0)$ a.s.

Comment: or perhaps Im just misinterpreting the statement

Comment: @user159813 The strong law is for N(0,1) I think. The exact notation in the book is "$\frac{S_n}{n} \to -1$ a.s."

Comment: oops. i realized i made another mistake though. thanks

Comment: Nope I think it applies to any rv, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law. plus remember $\bar{X}$ becomes normal as you increase n

Comment: @user159813 Edited. ^_^

Comment: Oh and $E(X_{n})=-1$, not $0$, thats where my confusion was

Comment: @user159813 Good point. Weird. But I think that the point of the exercise is that sample average doesn't always converge to sample mean. Perhaps one of the assumptions of SLLN is violated?

Comment: @user159813 The expected value is 0. It is even stated in the book...

Comment: Oh shoot you are right my bad, stupid mistake

Comment: I apologize for my confusion, didn't know there could be exception to strong law (which there are some shown in wiki page)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16680/discussion-between-user159813-and-bclc).

Comment: @user159813 Exceptions to the SLLN? There are no "exceptions" to the SLLN, only situations out of the frame of its hypothesis.

Comment: @Did I guess I phrased that wrong, I meant I wasn't aware of the conditions of the hypothesis, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @user159813 Right. No problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that, since the series $\sum\limits_nP(X_n\ne-1)$ converges, Borel-Cantelli lemma (the simple one) indicates that, almost surely, there exists some finite $N$ such that $X_n=-1$ for every $n\geqslant N$. Every such sequence $(X_n)$ is such that $S_n/n\to-1$ hence $P(S_n/n\to-1)=1$.

The strong law of large numbers does not apply, although $(X_n)$ is independent and $E(X_n)=0$ for every $n$, because the distribution of $X_n$ depends on $n$.

You wrote:

> Proving $S_n/n \to -1$ a.s. is equivalent to proving $P(S_n/n = -1 \ i.o.) = 1$ or $P(S_n/n = -1 \ ev.) = 1$. I think?

Really, no.

A general positive result in this vein is that $[Z_n\to -1]=[Z_n = -1 \ \text{eventually}]$ *when every $Z_n$ is integer valued* (but, even then, $[Z_n\to -1]$ is not the same event as $[Z_n = -1 \ \text{infinitely often}]$...). In your setting, the random variables $Z_n=S_n/n$ are not integer valued hence the inclusion $[Z_n = -1 \ \text{eventually}]\subset[Z_n\to -1]$ holds (it always does) but the other inclusion fails. As a matter of fact, $P(Z_n\to -1)=1$ but $[Z_n = -1 \ \text{eventually}]=\varnothing$ because $[Z_n=-1]=\varnothing$ for every $n$ because $P(X_1=-1)=0$ hence $Z_n\geqslant-1+2/n$ almost surely.

Comment: Is it correct to say that $\liminf (X_n = - 1) \subseteq (lim_{n \to \infty} S_n/n = - 1)$? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: DID, THANKS SO MUCH.

Comment: @user159813 there you go in case you were interested hahaha