# almost sure convergence of iid sum

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to reconcile what's intuitive with almost sure convergence.

Say I have iid $X_i$ with $P(X=+1) = \epsilon$, and $P(X=-M) = 1-\epsilon$, where $M$ is some very large (say $10^{100}$) number and $\epsilon$ is some very small number (say $10^{-100}$). Put $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

For all practical purposes, $S_n \rightarrow -\infty$. But can we say this holds almost surely? I'm curious about the dependence on $M, \epsilon$.

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908409/fair-game-in-williams

Answer (score 2):

The Strong Law of Large Number shows that $\dfrac{S_n}{n}$ converges almost surely to the expected value $E(X) = \epsilon - M(1-\epsilon)$. Therefore:

- If $E(X) < 0$, then $S_n$ converges to $-\infty$ almost surely.
- If $E(X) > 0$, then $S_n$ converges to $+\infty$ almost surely.

Finally, the Central Limit Theorem shows that $S_n$ does not converge almost surely if $E(X) = 0$.